# How can I migrate and merge a set of jira projects into a single project on a new server?

Tags: jira

We have a set of Jira projects on a server, that we need to move to a new server. At the same time we wish to merge those projects into a single project.

How can this be done, preserving workflows, columns, permissions, filters, components, etc.?

I see how to [migrate an entire server, one for one](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/migrating-jira-applications-to-another-server-938846962.html), but I am not seeing a way to merge and migrate select project instances. Also, the target server is already hosting many other projects, which we do not want to blow away

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no out of the box solution I'm aware of. In my opinion you have two options:

a) If this is a one-time task: [Merge your instances](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/merging-jira-instances-938847939.html) into one without merging projects together. Then, merge your projects e.g. [by bulk moving issues](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver/editing-multiple-issues-at-the-same-time-939937916.html) into one specific project. If you already have a server hosting many projects, then you could also setup a separate server where you do the migration on, move everything into one project and later move this single project back (if necessary).

b) If this migration should be a continuous task and your highest priority is the migration of issue data: there are Atlassian [marketplace apps which can synchronize issues](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?query=issue%20sync) between two different projects, so that you have the same issue data in two projects. You could use one of these apps and setup synchronizations between projects in the way like B to A, C to A, D to A, ... They will then do the job for you to "migrate" the issue data into one project. Please consider that such apps might not migrate EVERY data you want, e.g. you could lose certain settings, permissions or filters, because these apps are focused on actual issue data. Disclaimer: I'm a developer for one of these sync apps.